# Conditional / Posterior probability calculation from data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame which contains two columns: Consumer ID and Procedure Name.

A consumer can have more than one procedure name.

I need to understand the probability of a someone do a specific procedure given that he had done other procedure.

Example,

```
Consumer ID, Procedure Name
01, Procedure 01
01, Procedure 02
02, Procedure 01
```

So the probability of someone does the procedure 02 given that he has done procedure 01 is 50%.

Does anyone know a package, to do that? Or I will need to do run a Count If funciton?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can select those `Consumer_ID`s which have had procedure 1, create an indicator variable for whether they've also had procedure 2, and your probability is the average of this new indicator.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Consumer_ID) %>% 
  filter('Procedure 01' %in% Procedure_Name) %>% 
  summarise(had_p2 = 'Procedure 02' %in% Procedure_Name) %>% 
  summarise(p_2_given_1 = mean(had_p2))

# # A tibble: 1 x 1
#   p_2_given_1
#         <dbl>
# 1       0.500
```

Data used:

```
df <- data.table::fread("
Consumer_ID, Procedure_Name
01, Procedure 01
01, Procedure 02
02, Procedure 01
")
```

Comment: Thank you very much my friend.